# How to get column value without decimal in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I have two column in my mysql table **A** and **B** and I am fetching records like this:

```
select (A/B) from table
```

But problem is that Above query providing vales something like this:

```
12.00
3.4
78.9
```

But I want to get result like this:

```
12
3
78
```

Which MySQL function I will use for this ??

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you want 78.9 to be 78 then**

SELECT Floor(A/B) FROM table

**If you want 78.9 to be 79 then**

SELECT Ceiling(A/B) FROM table

Answer (score 8):

Just [ROUND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) your result:

```
SELECT ROUND(A/B, 0) FROM table
```

You can also combine ROUND with [FLOOR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) if you always want to round down.

Comment: Or [`FLOOR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) (based on OP's data sample).

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html