# Mysql how to select value front of decimal

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'am a newbie.. I'm sorry if my question is repost.. i want to ask how to get value front of decimal on mysql..

here my fiddle [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/addd0/1)

i try to use `FORMAT` on mysql

```
`SELECT FORMAT(desc,0) FROM table1`
```

the result is round.. in my case i dont want the result rounded.

i want the result is

```
1. 9
2. 9
3. 11
4. 11
```

sorry if i'm wrong.. thanks for help..

Comment: Use FLOOR,  select FLOOR(decs) from table1

Comment: See this question,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660199/how-to-get-column-value-without-decimal-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**FLOOR**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) it.

```
SELECT id, FLOOR(desc) FROM table1
```

This will remove the decimal places and return that whole number which you are looking for.

Result

> 1. 9
> 2. 9
> 3. 11
> 4. 11

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/addd0/34)**

Answer (score 2):

You can Use  `FLOOR()`

```
select  id,FLOOR(decs) from table1
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/addd0/46)

[SEE HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-numeric-functions.htm)

Comment: `CEIL` will make `1.3` a `2`, which is not what they desire.

Answer (score 0):

use round().. get all the data from your sql database then loop it

for example you have

```
$number = "1.00";
```

or

```
$number = 1.00;
```

then use round()

```
echo round($number);
```

the output is 1

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `ROUND` to truncate decimal places

```
SELECT ROUND(@column_name,0,1)
```

OR

example `select CAST(Round(MySum * 20.0 /100, 0) AS INT)`

`91 * 20 / 100 => 1820 / 100 => 18 (truncated from 18.20)`